# TYPO3: Create a FE user inside controller action

Tags: php, typo3, frontend, typo3-7.6.x

I'd like to create a FE user with a custom extension (created with the extension builder).
I don't want to use fe_user_registration or something similar because there are also many other custom features needed which will probably be lost when some moron accidentally updates it.

I'm using TYPO3 7.6.8

Comment: you can store data from your extension to table 'fe_users' with fields usergroup, username[should be unique] and password [should be md5]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Extbase comes with a [model](https://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_extbase_1_1_domain_1_1_model_1_1_frontend_user.html) and a [repository](https://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_extbase_1_1_domain_1_1_repository_1_1_frontend_user_repository.html) for manipulating frontend users. They also have a [model](https://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_extbase_1_1_domain_1_1_model_1_1_frontend_user_group.html) and a [repository](https://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_extbase_1_1_domain_1_1_repository_1_1_frontend_user_group_repository.html) for dealing with frontend user groups.

Use those, in the usual way. You might need to fiddle a bit to get storage pages right, but it'll work. I'm not sure if the password will be hashed automatically, so check that out.

First, inject a FrontendUserRepository where you want to use it:

```
/**
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Repository\FrontendUserRepository
 * @inject
 */
protected $frontendUserRepository;
```

Then create a frontend user and persist it using the repository:

```
$frontendUser = new FrontendUser();
$frontendUser->setUsername('myusername');
// Set more values

$this->frontendUserRepository->add($frontendUser);
```

Comment: It throws following error: `Fatal error: Class 'Vendor\ExtName\Controller\FrontendUser' not found in .../Classes/Controller/DummyController.php on line 84`. I think it has something to do with namespaces, doesn't it?

Comment: Yep, I just added `use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FrontendUser;` directly after the declaration of my own namespace and now it works like charm! Thanks a lot